# UX: Why not put the best answer to any question, before the question itself

Tags: feature-request, user-experience

This is more of a UX concern. I have used SO daily for the last 5 years, and I just noticed that most of the time I don't see the question's body, but instead I scroll to the answer immediatelly.

What about putting the best answer before the question's body and save us all that time scrolling?

Or what about a button to got to the best answer?

Comment: Erm... how 'bout no

Comment: like, below all of the answers? or just which ever one is the most upvoted, whichever one is accepted, or what

Comment: also it would be quite confusing for the layout to have an answer, then a question, then the rest of the answers.

Comment: No thanks - I would have to scroll down to check before down and close-voting.

Comment: @juanIsaza Are you just referencing the first comment? It's smart ass, but certainly not rude or abusive. Also, I have to agree with Kevin, that would be a mess of a layout. Having an answer before a question wouldn't even make sense. How can you know if an answer is necessarily relevant before even reading the question? It's not always obvious, and titles aren't always descriptive enough to act as context on their own.

Comment: I almost want to edit the question to put the answer (below) at the top, just so you can see how obnoxiously out of place it would be.

Comment: 'what about a button to got to the best answer?' which is that?  If you mean the accepted answer, it's easy to spot anyway 'cos of the big. green tick.  I don't see that an extra button would help that much.

Comment: @juan rude or abusive? Wait.... what? Care to explain how 'curt' = rude? Is there any insult or attack in the comment? Maybe you need a slightly thicker skin...   in any case, it would be a mess of a ui. And depending on the filter I use (active, votes or newest ), the top answer displayed may not be the 'best'. How do you reconcile the filters  with your idea?

Comment: Remarkable laziness, an asset to any programmer.  At the right time and in the right place.

Comment: Actually, what you *really* should be asking for is a collapsible question. That solves all your issues: a single click instantly shows the answer; if the answers are sorted by votes then the best answer (accepted or highest vote if non are accepted) is shown first.

Comment: @robinCTS; YES that's a good idea!

Answer (score 12):

**Why Not?**

- A question is rarely simple enough to be fully contained in the short question title. So a user really needs to see the question in its entirety in order to understand the answers.
- Sometimes the marked Best Answer (The one that helped the user the most) isn't the most helpful general answer. When the answers are all together, it's easier to see that there are more answers to the question, and by votes from the community, a user can see that another answer is possibly more useful.
- Stack Overflow is a Question and Answer Site. Q&A. The Question comes before the Answer when we say it, so that's the order people expect to see them in.
- The Answer before Question format feels awkward even on Jeopardy where it belongs; even though they give a title (A category) and the answer, it's still a puzzle to figure out what the exact question is. Displaying SO answers first would have a similar awkward effect.
- Not all questions have an accepted answer, so when you go to click on a question, it wouldn't be consistent if you were seeing an answer or a question first. It's easier to be consistent and know what to expect when you click.
- This would require major UI changes that I doubt could be added to just Stack Overflow and not the whole SE network, even though it sounds like you just want it here. (If you were thinking this for the whole SE network, post it on the Meta Stack Exchange).
- SO already has a bunch of things on their [6 to 8](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19514/363946) weeks list of things to do.

**Reasons why to do it:**

-... I've got nothing

Comment: _"A question is rarely simple enough to be fully contained in the short question title. So a user really needs to see the question in its entirety in order to understand the answers."_ - Yup, one of reasons I'm not too fond of Quora's question format.